# How to solve this this error. com.google.android.gms.tasks.task executors$zza cannot be cast to android.app.activity. I am new at Java & Android app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to verify user through phone number verification OTP code, now I am unable to fix this issue. I am new in android App development. I have connected Firebase with android studio, that's all fine except this error.

Logcat message error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskExecutors$zza cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
> at com.saqib.onlinefirregistration.VerifyOTP.sendVerificationCodeToUser(VerifyOTP.java:55)
> at com.saqib.onlinefirregistration.VerifyOTP.onCreate(VerifyOTP.java:48)

VerifyOTP.java:

```
public class VerifyOTP extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Variable
    PinView pinForUser;
    String codeBySystem;
    Button verifyButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.verify_otp);

            pinForUser = findViewById(R.id.pin_view);
            verifyButton = findViewById(R.id.verify_btn);
            String _PhoneNo = getIntent().getStringExtra("phoneNo");

            sendVerificationCodeToUser(_PhoneNo);    
    }

    private void sendVerificationCodeToUser(String phoneNo) {

        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
               phoneNo,                    // Phone No to verify
                60,                 //timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,           //Time unit
                (Activity) TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
        mCallback);
    }
    private  PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallback
            = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(@NonNull String s) {
            super.onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(s);
            codeBySystem =s;
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

            String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
            if (code!=null){
                pinForUser.setText(code);
                verifyCode(code);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {

            Toast.makeText(VerifyOTP.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };

    private void verifyCode(String code) {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(codeBySystem,code);

        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }

    private  void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){

                            Toast.makeText(VerifyOTP.this, "Verification Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                Toast.makeText(VerifyOTP.this, "Verification Not Completed! Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void signInUsingCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {

    }

    public void callNextScreenOTP( View view) {
        String code = pinForUser.getText().toString();
        if (!code.isEmpty()) {
            verifyCode(code);
        }
    }
};
```

How can I fix this issue? I have no idea about it, I did search for the same question but failed to find on Google, or stack overflow.

I want to verify user through phone number verification OTP code, now I am unable to fix this issue. I am new in android App development. I have connected Firebase with android studio, that's all fine except this error.

Answer (score 0):

`(Activity) TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD` line is wrong. It's clear from the error message that the cast cannot be made.

Since you're in activity, just `this` should do it in this place.

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace: **(Activity) TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,**

With: **this,**

Comment: This answer does not add anything more than [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70332833/2915423).